# Magento 2.2.1 Bug price by customer group not working after add to cart

Tags: magento2, customer, price, customer-group, tierprice

Magento 2.2.1 Bug price by customer group not working after add-to-cart

I have set product price based on customer group so if wholesalecustomer is logged in then price will be 20$ and the general customer is logged in then price will be 25$.

Thing is due to Magento 2.2.1 bug when I add to cart product then product price gets a change to Actual price 25$ for the wholesale customer as well.  It means when customer logged in and land on category page they can see customer group price but when they add to cart then Magento accepts the actual price 25$ also it turns category page pricing to general customer pricing.

So wholesale customer sees the same price as the general customer.

Really strange issue.  Did try catalog promotion rule as well but that's not working as well.  How can I fix this issue?  What's the solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like as some cache issue, I hope you try standard "in any strange situation clear cache first"  approach and run cache:flush  cli command

Comment: Cache is disable and developer mode is on.  people updated here as well.   Finding solution.  
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12114                                         https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10009